# OpenGL version still remains 1.1

Tags: opengl, windows-xp, desktop

I can't get OpenGL to work on my computer.

I have the latest drivers for my graphics card (nVidia Geforce 9500 GT, which supports OpenGL 3 and above!), but I run the OpenGL Extensions Viewer and it says I have OpenGL version 1.1!

And of course some games that need OpenGL can't run on my PC (I have Windows XP).

Can anyone help?

Comment: What you describe reeks of a driver problem. Did you really install the latest drivers as downloaded **from the GPU manufacturer's website** and installed those? Not just what Windows suggested you.

Comment: Yes of course i downloaded the drivers from nvidia, and i checked them.i see that current drivers version is correct..
The problem is that windows keeps overriding my card's openGL and uses the system default which is version 1.1

Comment: What "OpenGL Extensions Viewer" are you running? and are you sure that the version it displays isn't just the version it is using.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it my own Finally!
The problem was on motherboards integrated graphics. I just deleted the Nvidia Enhanced Display driver and the system started to use my GPU's openGL version.

Also i can't understand why some users gave me negative vote? I don't think i did anything wrong but asking a question.

Comment: I encounter the same issue.  I upgrade OpenGL driver but the opengl version of my GeForce 1660 is still 1.1. I found OpenGL version upgrading is only apply for integrated graphics card. I don't know how to delete the Nvidia Enhanced Display driver.